# Orion WordPress Manager. (orion.managewp.com)

Tags: wordpress

I need some help with reconnecting website on my Pro Sites (Orion WordPress Manager). There are a bunch of websites that give this error when I try to reconnect it using the correct credentials:

Sync Websites
44 minutes ago
CAT Generators (catgenset.com)
A server error was encountered during the processing of request (status code: 500). If the problem persists, please contact our support.

If any of you've faced this issue, please advise me on how to fix this.
Thanks

I have only tried to revert to previous version of the websites, I know that some plugins might be causing this, but I have ruled that out already.